# create an sql query to retrieve elements between 2 dates T1 and T2 or outside T1 and T2

Tags: sql

I wanna create an sql query to retrieve elements between 2 dates T1 and T2
if I don't get a result, I wanna get the result outside of these dates.
How can I do using only sql

```
select * from myTable where tmp >= T1 and tmp <= T2
select * from myTable where tmp < T1 or tmp > T2
```

Comment: what sql server are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query should solve the issue:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE
(tmp BETWEEN T1 AND T2)
OR
((tmp < T1 OR tmp > T2) AND (tmp NOT BETWEEN T1 AND T2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A query similar to this one should work:

```
(select * from myTable where tmp >= T1 and tmp <= T2)
UNION 
(select * from myTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from myTable where tmp >= T1 and tmp <= T2) AND tmp < T1 or tmp > T2)
```

This is not tested, considering the details provided so far.